# write data to csv file sheet 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, worksheet

I want to write data from datatable to CSV file starting from **Sheet 2** in C#.
any help please.
I have the following function to create CSV file.

```
public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dt, string strFilePath)
{

        // Create the CSV file to which grid data will be exported.
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
        // First we will write the headers.
        //DataTable dt = m_dsProducts.Tables[0];
        int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);

            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }

        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        // Now write all the rows.
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                {
                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                }
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }

        sw.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a strong suggestion: Don't try to invent your own CSV writer / reader. It seems to be easy, but there are dragons in the water, lots of dragons. Especially escaping strings is fun - how do you manage something line

Escaping that thin takes a lot of work.

So go ahead and use a library like: http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/ It'S free, fast and saves you days of work.

As a further questions: Is sheet 2 a excel file?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.
sheet 2 is csv sheet, because you can open csv from excel.
any help?

Comment: Ah you want to save to excel? than definitely use epplus - it even has a method to create a complete file from a db table.